# How to work in autocad from visual studio with windows forms using application.acadApplication?

Tags: c#, autocad

I need to do some operation in Autocad 2010 from Visual Studio 2008. When I try to access the Autocad from windows forms it doesn't work. Exception are thrown like `specified module could not be found`.

Inside the button Click I wrote the below code:

```
var obj = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.AcadApplication;
```

I referenced all necessary reference DLLs.

When I use interop methods it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you reference the acmgd.dll and acdbmgd.dll For in-process?

Or

Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.dll and Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.Common.dll for out of process?

It seems like you are trying to reference a com instance of the application while working in-process?

```
using AcApp = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application;
```

is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Both of the dll's i referenced process as well as interop.

Comment: @Sivaperuman What are you trying to do? are you just trying to access the application? Im going to need more information to help, buddy.